# Is it possible to update the maximum event log file size of a remote system?

Tags: windows, event-log

I've been searching a lot. Just wanted to know if by some way I can update the maximum log size of a remote system.

I'm working on event log handling and windows API's. Can someone please tell me if this is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why isn't that a relevant question?  I've been assigned a task to complete. I'm totally new to Event log handling. I just wanted to know if this is possible using some windows API's
Hope someone will reply. 
Thank you

Comment: The 1st thing you need to figure out is if is possible (and if yes, how) on your local system. Then (and only if possible :) ) think about remote systems. Note that there are lots of factors involved here: (e.g. the remote system might not be connected to a network, connectivity, firewalls, permissions, OS versions....) So on my opinion the question is too broad (and you didn't show any attempt to solve the problem yourself). Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to my question.
You can simply use the `EvtSetChannelConfigProperty()` function and set the property identifier id parameter to `EvtChannelLoggingConfigMaxSize`.

Pass a handle to the channel's configuration properties that the `EvtOpenChannelConfig()` function returns. You can choose between local machine or remote machines by adjusting the parameters of the  `EvtOpenChannelConfig()` function.

That's it.